# NodeJS + mongo-native: access with password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication

I need to access my mongodb from node with login and pass. Here how I do it now:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {
    auto_reconnect: true
});
var db = new Db('mybase', server);
```

What should I do to authentificate with password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`db.authenticate`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#authenticate) after opening a connection to the server.

```
db.open(function(err, db) {
    db.authenticate('username', 'password', function(err, result) {
        ...
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot of db.collection (...); calls. Does it means I have to add your code for every function, accessing to mongo?

Comment: @IlyaRusanen No, just once after `db` is opened.

Comment: Thank you, as always helped me a lot =)